# Windows Logoff Executable Missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, logoff

Windows 10 `Logoff.exe` is missing from `C:/Windows/System32`. I am able to "Sign Out" of windows via Start Menu. I am trying to instead sign out from a command line. How can I restore Windows Logoff Executable if it is missing?

What I've done is run `sfc /scannow` and when stuck at 23-percent I've pressed the `hotkey: ctrl+c` to attempt to cancel but eventually completed itself only afterwards. Also to note, it has not been re-located to syswow64 directory.

What could be the problem of having no logoff.exe in system32 of a Windows PC with the error message mentioning it not being found? Also, how does Windows 10 handle the action for `Sign Out via Start Menu`?

## SUGGESTIONS AS WORKAROUNDS

Windows 10 Home Edition does not have the logoff executable, so it's best to verify what edition your Windows installation is especially if it's Windows 10.

Alternatively you may logoff from the commandline (*or terminal*) via `shutdown.exe /l` assuming that you have the shutdown executable within your system32 directory.

- Shutdown Executable to Logoff instead

  - `shutdown.exe /l` regular instance without force or timer
  - `shutdown.exe /l /t 0` includes timer
  - `shutdown.exe /l /f` avoid prompts by forcing apps to close includes timer
  - `shutdown.exe /l /t 0 /f` immediately avoids prompts by forcing apps to close

See below (*user no. 1686 posted*) for other ways that should be more difficult to logoff windows w/out it's executable by using the powershell terminal or scripting language even with the use of third party apps like autohotkey.

Comment: You would use the correct command rather than an incorrect one. `shutdown /l`. See `shutdown /?`. Did you read your stuff on the internet?

Comment: please check: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/162465/285641

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Logoff.exe` is not available on Windows Home.

You could do the same by using the
[Shutdown command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown),
with the parameter `/l` for "Log off".

The parameter `/f` could be useful to force running applications to close. Use `/t 0` to force immediate execution.

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the problem of having no logoff.exe in system32 of a Windows PC

If I remember correctly, logoff.exe is technically part of the "Terminal Services" feature (together with qwinsta.exe, tslist.exe, and so on) – so it will be missing in Windows Home, because the Home edition doesn't have the Terminal Services feature.

> Also, how does Windows 10 handle the action for Sign Out via Start Menu?

It doesn't rely on external .exe files; it just directly does *the same thing that logoff.exe does* – it calls the ExitWindowsEx() Win32 function.

You could do this e.g. from a PowerShell script using:

```
$api = Add-Type -PassThru -Name Win32Api -MemberDefinition @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int ExitWindowsEx(int uFlags, int dwReason);
"@;
$api::ExitWindowsEx(0, 0);
```

...or from C, C# (P/Invoke), AutoHotkey (DllCall), Python (ctypes), etc.